# Linksys wusb6300 not starting after reboot

Tags: networking, 16.04, usb, lts, ubuntu-gnome

I have succesfully installed this usb wifi adapter on my ubuntu-gnome system. However, when I reboot my system, it doesn't start automatically. I have to unplug it and when I plug it back in, it does work again. I would like to find a way to let it boot with my pc, so I don't have to un/replug this wifi adapter because it is on the back of my pc.

[lsmod + lsusb after reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23416533/)

Thanks in advance

Niels

Comment: Restart your computer and while the adapter is ***not*** working, run `lsmod > wifi.txt` and `lsusb >> wifi.txt` and then reconnect the adapter and paste the contents of the `wifi.txt` file on [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Put the link to that paste in your question please

Comment: I hope you can use it

Comment: Whenever it's not working, try these two commands and let me know if it works: `sudo modprobe -r 8812au` & `sudo modprobe 8812au`.

Comment: If I run these commands AFTER I restarted my pc, it will start without un/replugging it. So how can I automate this?

Comment: Good! It's working. Just edit `/etc/rc.local` with whatever text editor you like and add these lines right above where it says `exit 0`. `modprobe -r 8812au` `sleep 1` `modprobe 8812au` (all being on separate lines.) Let me know if it works so I can post it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it was solved. I added an answer accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47921/discussion-between-owen-hines-and-niels-van-laerhoven).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's output of `lsmod` and `lsusb` **before** unplugging and plugging back in the adapter after a reboot, the ID of the device/driver was `8112au`.

To manually initiate the device driver, use the commands

```
modprobe -r 8812au
modprobe 8812au
```

Finally, automate this by adding these three lines to `/etc/rc.local` after the line that reads `exit 0`:

```
modprobe -r 8812au
sleep 1
modprobe 8812au
```

The driver should now automatically be started on boot.